# Algorithm for creating anonymous unique identifier from serial number

Tags: algorithm, privacy

I would like to log some simple usage statistics for a mobile application. For the privacy of my users, I would prefer not to store their actual device serial number in the database if possible. Is there a simple algorithm that can hash or transform a serial number into an anonymous identifier and cannot be reversed, while still guaranteeing uniqueness?

Comment: If it cannot be reversed anyway, why not just use a Guid?

Comment: I was looking for something based on the device serial number so that uninstall/reinstalls or new versions would generate the same ID instead of falsely inflating the user counter. It looks like I will just have to accept this small skew and will go with something like a GUID/UUID.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want to use [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).  Pretty much all languages have this.
  As far as I know, they cannot be reversed to get back the original "seed".

Comment: Based on my desire to use the device serial number as the seed for predictable results, and the fact that I am using javascript, I am going with this: 
http://davidbau.com/encode/seedrandom.js
explained here:
http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html
I found it from reading your link, and then following comment links, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a HASH of the devices serial number. A hash is by definition a one way encryption. Use the SHA-256 algorithm.

Now, depending on the size of the input, hash functions may create some collisions, this would cause your unique identifier to be not-unique in some (very rare) cases. To avoid this you could append some other piece of arbitrary information to it like IP address or a time stamp.

```
[SHA-256 of serial number][Time Stamp][Data to store]
```